# Как сделать страничку с товаром на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать страничку с фотографиями товара, кнопкой "купить" и описанием?

Comment: поискать модуль для WP в сети интернет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут 2 варианта: 1й - плагин [WP E-commerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/) или аналогичный. 2й - копать в сторону [Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types)

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос а накой ляд нужно к движку для блогов, городить костыли чтобы сделать магазин.
Есть движки для магазаниов пользуйтесь ими.

Answer (score 1):

Отличный плагин [WpPage](http://kot.yadoma.wppage.e-autopay.com)
Можно попробовать бесплатно 7 дней. Мне очень понравился, легко делается дизайн, убираются боковые колонки и вообще все лишнее блоговское, кнопки купить и т.п. и т.д. имеются.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего использовать дополнительные поля, если вы разбираетесь в програмировании то это не составит вам труда сделать, тем более всегда удобно, можно настроить под любые нужны, достаточно прочитать мануал (кодекс) о том как самим устанавливать и выводить дополнительные поля. Т.е без всяких плагинов, и не нужных функций вы свой пост превратите в страничку с товаром, его фото, описанием, и дополнительными полями, такими как цена, цвет, да что угодно можете там дополнить и вывести. Ну а если нет, и вам нужно что то по более, тогда только специальные плагины.Типа "woocommerce" который очень кстати популярен. Но если вы хотите сделать полноценный магазин то используйте такие CMS системы как OpenCart, Magneto, PrestaShop, Ecommerce